# C# Change memory of 2 objects pointing to same address

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding updating of an object's memory.
If I have two object equal to each other and I change the property of one, it changes the property of the other. That's fine.
If I then make one object equal to a third object, the first two objects have lost all relationship.
Is there a way to make both the first and second equal to the third by only explicitly making one equal to the third?

```
var a = new ObjectA();
var b = a;
var equality = a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode() // true => makes sense
var c = new ObjectA();
a = c;
equality = a.GetHashCode() == c.GetHashCode() // true => makes sense
equality = a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode() // false => Is it possible to make this true with out again explicitly setting it to be equal
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `If I have two object equal to each other and I change the property of one, it changes the property of the other.` that means you only have a single object, not two. `b` and `a` are the same object referenced through different variables. `c` is a new object and `a=c` discards whatever was stored in `a` replacing it with a reference to `c`

Comment: Variables are only references to objects, not the objects themselves. Think of them as labels or Post-Its attached to the actual object. In your question there are only 2 objects, created by the two `new ObjectA()`. `b = a` and `c = a` moves around the labels, not the objects

Comment: when you assign a to b, both a and b refer to the same object. When you change a property of the object through one of these references, it reflects on both of them.

However, when you assign a to c, a starts referring to a new object, while b still refers to the original object. Hence, a and b are no longer pointing to the same object and their GetHashCode() will be different.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks you for your answers. I have expressed myself poorly with variable and object. I guess my question is, if b=a, is there a way to make a=c resulting in b=c without explicitly writing b=c. This would be very convenient for example, for caching where the property of cached object points to another cached object assuming the second cached object is updated.

Comment: There's no problem to solve. You confuse variables and the references stored in them for actual objects. There's no caching. No second cached object. There are only two `ObjectA` instances in the question. The variables `a`, `b` and `c` only store references to those two objects. You could have 100 variables pointing to those 2 objects

Comment: `whoever was so kind as to downgrade my question` I didn't downvote but this is a very basic question no matter the language - what are variables? It's not a matter of wording or expressing yourself.

Comment: Variables are like labels, mailboxes or drawers. If you have 2 cups and put both in the same drawer, does that turn 2 cups into 1? Does scratching one cup scratch the other in the same place? Does moving a cup from one drawer to another change the cup?

Comment: Trivially, you can use an array of size 1 to hold a shared object, and then pass that array around. To access the shared object you'd just access `array[0]`, and to update the object for everything that had a reference to the array, you'd just do `array[0] = newObject;`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Again, thank you for your comment. But again, it isn't about the difference between variables and objects. Carrying on with your analogy, if I have one cup with two labels on it, they both represent that cup. If I want that cup to be a different cup, then I have to manually move both labels to the new cup. That is what I want to avoid. One way, which would be cumbersome, is to give the original cup the same volume as the new cup and add the scratch from the new cup. But I don't want do that if I can manage it. If there is no solution, that is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

> var a = new ObjectA();

Now you have one object

> var b = a;

Now you have two *references* pointing to the *same* object.

> var c = new ObjectA();
> a = c;

Now you have two (different) objects, and three references.

I think the important thing you are missing is [value vs reference equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons). Reference types, i.e. classes default to reference equality, that means you will compare the *address* of the objects, not the content. You can change this by overriding the Equals/GetHashCode methods, but you need to be careful if your object is mutable, since it can make your object incompatible with dictionaries and other collections that relies on the HashCode never changing.

Value types, i.e. structs default to value equality, meaning the actual contents are compared.

Records default also default to value equality, and have some nice syntax to help make them be immutable, avoiding the HashCode problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am actually looking for a solution to the above problem(assuming there is one). I know how references work and I am trying to get around it.

Comment: @Njun Use a struct instead of an class, that way you will use value equality, and ensure all of the values compare the same.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using Reflection to manually set properties a bit like this:

```
var a = SomeObject();
var b = a;
var equality = object.ReferenceEquals(a, b) // true of course
var c = SomeObject();
a.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(p => 
{
    var value = c.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(c);
    p.SetValue(a, value); 
});
equality = object.ReferenceEquals(a, b) // still true
```

Now a, b and c are equivalent.
Otherwise @InBetween has a good answer.
Sorry if my question was not phrased so well.

Comment: You seem to be using hashcode equality as equivalent to object equality. That is deeply wrong, don't do that. Hashcode guidelines simply state that two objects that are equal (be it reference or value equality) *must* return the same hashcode. But there is no rule whatsoever that obliges two *distinct* objects to return diferent hashcodes. If you want to test for reference equality use `Object.ReferenceEquals` or `Equals(obj o)`. If you want to test value equality (type implements `Equatable<T>`) use `Equals(T t)`.

Comment: This solution and mine are deeply different. Your reference equalities will not return all `true` unless `SomeObject()` is actually returning the same object every time its called. You seem to have a deep misunderstanding between reference and value equality semantics. Your code shoud work with value equality but not with reference. If `object()` returns a new object everytime, `a` and `c` and `b` and `c` are not the same object.

Comment: Oh true, a and c are not equal with ReferenceEquals, only the properties are the same. a and b are still the same object and this is what I wanted to preserve.